# How to integrate pandas with Robot framework and run queries

Tags: python, pandas, robotframework

I am developing a Data Validation Framework for a product using Robot Framework and Pandas. I am establishing DB connection using robot framework like below by reading configuration from `sample.robot` file -

```
*** Settings ***
Variables  ./sample.yaml
*** Variables ***
${DB1Host}          ${db1host}
${DB1Name}          ${db1name}
${DB1Pass}          ${db1pwd}
${DB1Port}          ${db1port}
${DB1User}          ${db1user}

${DB2Host}          ${db2host}
${DB2Name}          ${db2name}
${DB2Pass}          ${db2pwd}
${DB2Port}          ${db2port}
${DB2User}          ${db2user}

***Keywords***
Connect To DataBase
    [Documentation]  Establish Connection On DataBase1
    ${data_base1}=    Get Library Instance    DB1
    log to console  Data_Base1 Instance : ${data_base1}
    DB1.Connect To Database    pymysql  ${DB1Name}  ${DB1User}   ${DB1Pass}   
    ${DB1Host}   ${DB1Port}
    log to console  Connected to Data_Base1
    [Return]  ${data_base1}
```

Similarly connecting to second Database

Now i want to call another python library using pandas and execute select query and dropduplicates();

```
import pandas as pd

SHARING_DATA = dict()

def get_data(conn_rd,conn_sc):
    global SHARING_DATA
    df1= pd.read_sql("""<DB1 inner joint query>""", con=conn_rd).drop_duplicates
    print(df1)

    df2 = pd.read_sql("""<DB2 inner joint query> """, con=conn_sc).drop_duplicates()
    print(df2)
    SHARING_DATA[SUITE_NAME] = dict()
    SHARING_DATA[SUITE_NAME]["df1"] = df1
    SHARING_DATA[SUITE_NAME]["df2"] = df2
```

So that i can perform

```
1. .drop_duplicates()

2. if SHARING_DATA[SUITE_NAME]["df1"].count().equals(SHARING_DATA[SUITE_NAME]["df2"].count()):

And

3. db1-db2 = SHARING_DATA[SUITE_NAME]["df1"] .merge(SHARING_DATA[SUITE_NAME]["df2"], how='left', indicator=True)
        db1-db2 = db1-db2[(db1-db2['_merge'] == 'left_only')].copy()
        db1-db2 = db1-db2.drop(columns='_merge').copy()
        print('STATUS    : FAIL, Records missing in target\n')
        print(db1-db2.head())
```

To compare Data between two database. How can i make very adaptive same in robot framework or how can i reuse the above comparisions in robot framework

Answer (score 0):

You may include any Python libraries to your Robot Framework test cases by adding the following to the settings section of the test suite (expects the script to be in the same folder as the test file):

```
*** Settings ***
Library    ${CURDIR}${/}python_script.py
```

If your provided python script was included in that way, you could then call any implemented functions in the Robot test case in the following way:

```
*** Test Cases ***
Call a function from the Python script
    Get Data  ${CONNECTION_1}  ${CONNECTION_2}
```

You can add more parameters to the Python functions and then add more keyword parameters to the `Get Data` keyword as well to add functionality.

If you have anything implemented in Python it's very easy to transfer it into a Robot test suite by just calling the python functions in the explained way. I hope this answer was helpful as I'm not completely sure about the end result you're looking for but it definitely helps adapting python libraries to Robot Framework :)